# how to assign 0 value for not existing records

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

in snowflake, while using

```
select sum(sale)
from ..
group by date
```

Friday is not returned, as no records for Friday, January 10th exists.

**how to get explicit 0 value for missing data on Friday 10th?**

| date | weekday | sale | clerk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-06 | Monday | 1,500 | John |
| 2020-01-07 | Tuesday | 1,300 | John |
| 2020-01-08 | Wednesday | 1,400 | John |
| 2020-01-09 | Thursday | 1,600 | John |
| 2020-01-11 | Saturday | 1,700 | John |
| 2020-01-12 | Sunday | 1,200 | John |
| 2020-01-06 | Monday | 1,200 | Peter |
| 2020-01-07 | Tuesday | 1,100 | Peter |
| 2020-01-08 | Wednesday | 1,700 | Peter |
| 2020-01-09 | Thursday | 1,500 | Peter |
| 2020-01-11 | Saturday | 1,000 | Peter |
| 2020-01-12 | Sunday | 1,900 | Peter |

Comment: I would think is a bit challenging as it can be any day without sales and how would you know the day without a row? The easiest way would be to insert a row for that day with 0 sales.

Comment: let's say the user access I was offered with is read only

Answer (score 2):

You will need 3 elements:

- A list of all dates, so we can find a number for each.
- A right/left join, so the join works even if there's no data for that day
- A `IFNULL()`, to transform a null value for a date into a 0.

For example:

```sql
with all_dates as (
    select dateadd('day', row_number() over(order by 0) -1, '2020-01-01') generated_day
    from table(generator(rowcount => 6))
), data as (
    select '2020-01-01'::date d, 3 value
    union all select '2020-01-04', 7
)

select generated_day, ifnull(value, 0)
from data a
right join all_dates b
on a.d=b.generated_day
;
```

[image]

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/65822976/132438.